# How can I grant Windows permission to access a WSL user home directory?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Ubuntu installed using WSL 2 with two users, one is the account created when I first opened the installation, and the other is the account I created using the `adduser` command. When I try to access the first account's home directory using File Explorer everything works fine, but when I try to access the second account, I get an error message saying that "You might not have permission to use this network resource."

I noticed that I can use `chmod 777` on the second account's home directory to allow Windows access to it, but is there any other way to do this without giving everyone permission?

Comment: I don't know if this solution will work with WSL but it can't hurt to try: `https://askubuntu.com/questions/487527/give-specific-user-permission-to-write-to-a-folder-using-w-notation`. Obviously change it to read permission to satisfy your situation. Let us know if it works.

Comment: Also, look at this from MSFT: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/file-permissions` Let us know if it works.

Comment: Add the default user (user1) to user2's group: https://superuser.com/questions/487296/how-do-i-add-users-to-another-users-group, then you can set user2's home directory to `770` or similar

Comment: @Brian Running `setfacl -m u:[user1]:rwx [user2]/` seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Running `usermod -a -G [user2] [user1]` and setting user2's home directory's permissions to 770 also works. Thanks!